# A bug in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a UIMenuController calling a modal view, however the context menu doesn't hide itself upon calling the modal view. The context menu always hides itself when it's out of focus. I don't think this is the right behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu controller probably has no idea you've presented a modal view controller, so you just need to hide it yourself using `setMenuVisible:animated:`.

I haven't used UIMenuController myself, but that sounds like reasonable behaviour to me.